# Recover data of dropped tables without backup

Tags: sql-server

I did a blunder in my client database. I have dropped all tables and created new tables with same name in client database. I lost all client data. I don’t have any backup of client DB. Can you please let me know if I can recover data of old tables.

Comment: Without backups, you're kinda screwed.

Comment: Not scheduling a backup on client data is a big mistake. You cannot get the data without backup.

Comment: Chalk this one up to a "life-lesson"

Comment: check if the server itself is being backed up, either the server image or all the files on it.

Comment: search how to restore data from the transaction logs

Comment: if you are very, very lucky you might be able to restore your tables from the transaction log.  If your database is in simple mode then your logs might already be truncated though.  Here's an article that discusses some of the steps you could take: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/

Answer (score 0):

Few options .All untested  and i am not sure,how consistent the database will be

1.[RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/experimental-tools/sql-log-rescue/walkthrough) Provides a tool called `SQL Log Rescue`..It claims to do `View and recover deleted and modified data`

2.Volume Shadow Copy service

some reference of what this means :(emphasis mine)

> This service allows Windows to take automatic or manual backups, or snapshots, of the current state of the files on a particular volume (drive letter). The important part of this process is that these backups can be taken of files even if they are open. **Therefore, this provides a mechanism that backup programs and Windows can use to retain a reliable history of a computer's files**

Below is a step by step tutorial on how to do this

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-recover-files-and-folders-using-shadow-volume-copies/